# Integrate video and iframe in a post type gallery

Tags: posts, theme-development, images, gallery, videos

I'm new to wordpress.
I was making a theme with articles in a Gallery like style with swiper

[image]

And I wanted add video (from vimeo/youtube ...)
I've actually copied a php code for a Image **only** gallery

```
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1, // Using -1 loads all posts
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', // This ensures images are in the order set in the page media manager
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', // Make sure it doesn't pull other resources, like videos
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // Important part - ensures the associated images are loaded
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);
```

And I wanted to know how to add video there.
I tried adding
`'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'video', 'iframe',`
but it didn't do anything.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [See this](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/393). Anyway, it's off-topic here.

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem. Maybe my question was not well explained. Thus, my problem doesn't have any link with swiper. I just wanted to add more content to the gallery than just "image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `image` is not a proper mime type. You can see a [list of mime-types here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types#Default_allowed_mime_types) - so based off the linked list we need to pass an array of what we need:

```
$supported_mimes = array(
    'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png',
    'video/avi', 'video/x-flv', 'video/mp4', 'video/ogg', 'video/webm',

);

$args = array(
    'numberposts'       => -1, // Using -1 loads all posts
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order', // This ensures images are in the order set in the page media manager
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type'    => $supported_mimes
    'post_parent'       => $post->ID, // Important part - ensures the associated images are loaded
    'post_status'       => null,
    'post_type'         => 'attachment'
);
```

I think the bigger problem is enabling WordPress to allow you to create a gallery with both images and videos but as far as this goes, this is just pulling media uploaded to that post.